# Sample Project for NHibernate Search using Lucene.Net

Tags: nhibernate.search

Is there any Asp Dotnet projects samples available using Lucene Dotnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am personally a huge fan of the [LINQ to Lucene project](http://linqtolucene.codeplex.com/).

It did not meet all of our requirements, but with the source code available it was a snap to make adjustments.

An easy to follow simple example of use can be found at [Hacky Hacky](http://vijay.screamingpens.com/archive/2008/07/21/linq-amp-lambda-part-4-lucene.net.aspx)

Also, a quick search at Code Project will quickly show you numerous uses of Lucene.net. While they are frequently not ASP.NET projects out of the box; with a little adaptation you should be able to employ many of the libraries there in a webform project.

A great starter article there can be found at [Introducing Lucene.Net](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/IntroducingLucene.aspx).

Comment: thanks Ian for your response and it will be usefull for me to do the project in LINQ and Lucene.Right Now am using Nhibernate insted of LINQ. Are you done any thing using NHibernate.Search and Lucene. Net